# Reflection is not working

Tags: java, reflection

I am new to reflection. I am facing some error. Please help. Below is my code:

EmployeeClass.java:

```
public class EmployeeClass {

    private String empID;
    private String empName;

    public String getEmpID() {
        return empID;
    }

    public void setEmpID(String empID) {
        this.empID = empID;
    }

    public String getEmpName() {
        return empName;
    }

    public void setEmpName(String empName) {
        this.empName = empName;
    }

    public EmployeeClass(String empID, String empName) { 
        this.empID = empID;
        this.empName = empName;
    }

    public String getAllDetails() {
        return empID + " " + empName;
    }

}
```

ReflectionClass.java:

```
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

public class ReflectionClass {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        EmployeeClass emp = new EmployeeClass("1", "Emp1");
        Method method = null;
        try {
            method = emp.getClass().getMethod("getAllDetails", null);
            System.out.println(method.invoke(null, null));
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException | SecurityException
                | IllegalAccessException | IllegalArgumentException
                | InvocationTargetException e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }


    }

}
```

While running the ReflectionClass.java, I'm getting the following error:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException

```
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
                at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
                at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
                at myprgs.programs.ReflectionClass.main(ReflectionClass.java:14)
```

Comment: code method.invoke(null, null) is used for calling static methods

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to pass the object of the class (which contains your method) while calling `invoke()`, as shown below:

```
method.invoke(emp, null);
```

Change:

```
System.out.println(method.invoke(null, null));
```

To:

```
System.out.println(method.invoke(emp, null));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 method = emp.getClass().getMethod("getAllDetails", null);
            System.out.println(method.invoke(null, null));
```

[**`java.lang.reflect.Method.(Object obj, Object... args)`**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#invoke%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object...%29): The first argument is the object instance on which this particular method is to be invoked. However, the first argument should be **`null`**, If the method is **`static`**. So, you need to invoke with instance `emp` of `EmployeeClass`:

```
System.out.println(method.invoke(emp, null));
```

Again the second argument `args` of `invoke()`: (I am assuming i might have already know it), If the number of formal parameters required by the underlying method is 0, the supplied `args` array may be of length `0`or `null`.

Answer (score 0):

Changed the main method - method.invoke needs the employee object.

public static void main(String[] args) {

```
    Employee emp = new Employee("1", "Emp1");
    Method method = null;
    try {
        method = emp.getClass().getMethod("getAllDetails", null);
        System.out.println(method.invoke(emp, null));
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```